# How to create multiple datetimepickers in django template (for loop) and jquery

Tags: python, jquery, django, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I am having trouble getting django to display multiple datetimepickers in tabs on a html page. I can get them to work if I specify each element in the jquery outside of a loop, but when I put it in a loop, they don't show (only shows an empty input text box). As this has to be done on an array of varying sizes (min length of 1 and no max), I can't hard code each individual datetimepicker.  The for loop on the django template html page works, and each tab and the sections where the datetimepickers go is made, but the jquery won't work.

I have tried to make the 4 datetimepickers via a loop (4 per tab, can have 1+ tabs), and they don't create the datetimepicker object. Just creates a input text box.

I have also tried putting them all into a class=datetimepicker, which does work, but then I can't add in default data from the array to fill in each datetimepicker, as the only function in jquery is a single one calling the class .datetimepicker. Tried $('#date1').datetimepicker({ defaultDate: array[counter][0] }) in an array to fill in each tab for the date1 datetimepicker, and that does not work either.

excluding usual django template code and just putting in the section not working:

```
------------------- template html ------------------------

{% if entryList %}
  <ul id="tab_links" class="nav nav-tabs justify-content-center">
    {% for entry in entryList %}
      {% if forloop.first %} <!-- won't go through the first iteration otherwise -->
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_{{forloop.counter0}}">{{entry.0}}</a></li>
      {% else %}
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" data-toggle="tab" href="#tab_{{forloop.counter0}}">{{entry.0}}</a></li>
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>

  <div id="tab_content" class="tab-content">
    {% for entry in entryList %}
      {% if forloop.first %}
        <div id="tab_{{forloop.counter0}}" class="tab-pane fade in active">
          <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
            <tr>
              <td> date1: </td>
              <td style="position:relative">
                <input class="datetimepicker" type="text" id="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" name="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" "> 
              </td>
                <!-- other input like txt boxes or drop down menus -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> date2: </td>
              <td style="position:relative">
                <input class="datetimepicker" type="text" id="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" name="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" "> 
              </td>
                <!-- other input like txt boxes or drop down menus -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> date3: </td>
              <td style="position:relative">
                <input class="datetimepicker" type="text" id="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" name="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" "> 
              </td>
                <!-- other input like txt boxes or drop down menus -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> date4: </td>
              <td style="position:relative">
                <input class="datetimepicker" type="text" id="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" name="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" "> 
              </td>
                <!-- other input like txt boxes or drop down menus -->
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
       {% else %}
         <div id="tab_{{forloop.counter0}}" class="tab-pane fade">
           <table cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10">
             <tr>
              <td> date1: </td>
              <td style="position:relative">
                <input class="datetimepicker" type="text" id="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" name="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" "> 
              </td>
                <!-- other input like txt boxes or drop down menus -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> date2: </td>
              <td style="position:relative">
                <input class="datetimepicker" type="text" id="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" name="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" "> 
              </td>
                <!-- other input like txt boxes or drop down menus -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> date3: </td>
              <td style="position:relative">
                <input class="datetimepicker" type="text" id="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" name="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" "> 
              </td>
                <!-- other input like txt boxes or drop down menus -->
            </tr>
            <tr>
              <td> date4: </td>
              <td style="position:relative">
                <input class="datetimepicker" type="text" id="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" name="date_{{forloop.counter0}}" "> 
              </td>
                <!-- other input like txt boxes or drop down menus -->
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
       {% endif %}
      {% endfor %}
    </div>
.
.  other data on template html
.
<script>    var numOfTabs = {{entryListLength}};
        var jsondataList = {{json_dataList|safe}};
</script>
<script src="{% static 'js/dates.js' %}"> </script>  <!-- right before /body tag -->

--------------------------------js/dates.js------------------------------

// gotta use a for loop to get all tabs
// 4 parts of the array are dates: 7 - date rec, 10 - date ret, 16 - key req date, 17 - key rec date

var count = 0;

for (count; count < numOfTabs; count++) {
    // date1
    if ((jsondataList != null) && (jsondataList.length != 0) && (jsondataList[count][7] != null) && (jsondataList[count][7].length != 0)) {
        var datearr = jsondataList[count][7].split(/-|\s|:/);
        var date1 = new Date(datearr[0], datearr[1] - 1, datearr[2], datearr[3], datearr[4], datearr[5]);
        var inName = "#date1_" + count;
        console.log('array slot : ', count, 7, date1, inName);
        $(function() {
            $(inName).datetimepicker({
                useCurrent:false,
                  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
                defaultDate: date1,
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(function() {
            $("#date1_" + count).datetimepicker({
              format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
            });
        });
    }
    // date2
    if ((jsondataList != null) && (jsondataList.length != 0) && (jsondataList[count][10] != null) && (jsondataList[count][10].length != 0)) {
        var datearr = jsondataList[count][10].split(/-|\s|:/);
        var date2 = new Date(datearr[0], datearr[1] - 1, datearr[2], datearr[3], datearr[4], datearr[5]);
        var inName = "#date2_" + count;
        console.log('array slot : ', count, 10, date2, inName);
        $(function() {
            $(inName).datetimepicker({
                useCurrent:false,
                  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
                defaultDate: date2,
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(function() {
            $("#date2_" + count).datetimepicker({
              format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
            });
        });
    }
// date3
    if ((jsondataList != null) && (jsondataList.length != 0) && (jsondataList[count][16] != null) && (jsondataList[count][16].length != 0)) {
        var datearr = jsondataList[count][16].split(/-|\s|:/);
        var date3 = new Date(datearr[0], datearr[1] - 1, datearr[2], datearr[3], datearr[4], datearr[5]);
        var inName = "#date3_" + count;
        console.log('array slot : ', count, 16, date3, inName);
        $(function() {
            $(inName).datetimepicker({
                useCurrent:false,
                  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
                defaultDate: date3,
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(function() {
            $("#date3_" + count).datetimepicker({
              format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
            });
        });
    }
// date4
    if ((jsondataList != null) && (jsondataList.length != 0) && (jsondataList[count][17] != null) && (jsondataList[count][17].length != 0)) {
        var datearr = jsondataList[count][17].split(/-|\s|:/);
        var date4 = new Date(datearr[0], datearr[1] - 1, datearr[2], datearr[3], datearr[4], datearr[5]);
        var inName = "#date4_" + count;
        console.log('array slot : ', count, 17, date4, inName);
        $(function() {
            $(inName).datetimepicker({
                useCurrent:false,
                  format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
                defaultDate: date4,
            });
        });
    } else {
        $(function() {
            $("#date4_" + count).datetimepicker({
              format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
            });
        });
    }
}

The code for the class version is 

        $(function() {
            $(".datetimepicker").datetimepicker();
        });
*this works for making datetimepickers, but can't put default values in.
```

The expected result is that it has tabs on the page, with the number equal to the size of the list of arrays/lists i.e. list[x][y] there would be x tabs. On each tab is y input variables (text boxes, areas, etc.) as well as 4 datetimepickers. The datetimepickers should display the default value from the list for each tab, and have the option to choose a different value based on clicking the datetimepicker object and a calendar popping up.

The actual output shows everything but the datetimepickers. The datetimepickers are shown as textboxes, don't populate the default values, and don't load the calendar when clicked on (just act like textboxes instead). If I make the js as a function acting on just the class itself, it will make the datetimepicker objects, but doesn't allow me to put in default values.

Everything else in the template works, just the datetimepickers when in a loop that don't. Been trying for a couple of weeks now to figure it out.

EDIT:

Also, a thing to note: if I create each of the 4 datetimepickers outside a loop, then for the tab I create them for it will work, but since I don't know how many tabs I'll have I have to do it dynamically, hence why their in a javascript loop.

Comment: can anybody offer some help or advice?

Answer (score 0):

figured out a solution for anyone else who has the same or similar problem. Instead of directly making the datetimepickers in the loop, I separated the datetimepicker function from the loop and just call it.

i.e:

```
for loop
    ....
    ....
    call mydatetimepicker(variable, variable)

mydatetimepicker(variable, variable) {
 code to create a datetimepicker
}
```

for the life of me couldn't get it to work inside the loop, but as soon as i separate them it works fine even with the default dates.